# Layout for items of specific category

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a bunch of categories and items in Joomla and I want one of the categories to be different from the others - these category items have to use different layout. I'm not using any extensions, just `com_content`. I've tried creating copies of `default.php` in my `/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl` but I can't assign it to my category.
Any help would be appreciated. Seems like adding new layouts to modules is much easier, or maybe I'm just getting something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried this but I think you will firstly have to do a template override. You can see how this is done via the link below:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Then, in the default.php you could try adding the following:

```
if (JRequest::getVar('id')=='22' && JRequest::getVar('view')=='category' && JRequest::getVar('option')=='com_content') {
  //layout for category goes in here
}
else {
  //default category layout
}
```

You will of course need to change `22` to the `ID` of your category you want to change the layout for.

Comment: I went this way, I'm only modifying default.php and I just check my category name and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the link given below to assign the different template to specific menu item. You can assign the `categorylist` menu type in the menu item from menu manager and assign the template to the particular menu from template manager. **Note** that you cannot assign the default template to individual pages.For more information go to this link :

[[How do you assign a template to a specific page?](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_assign_a_template_to_a_specific_page%3F)

Comment: there is no content in the link you provided ;)

Answer (score 1):

For 1.6 or later alternative layouts work like layout overrides but are stored in a file with a different name. So instead of being called default.php they might be named myalternatelayout.php.  Alternate layouts are assigned to items when you create or edit them.

Alternate menu item layouts require you to create both the php file and an xml title with same name, so myalternatemenulayout.php and myalternatemenulayout.xml. These will show up when you create a new menu item.

I'm a little unclear whether what you want to do is programmatically assign the layouts so you don't have to do it each time. I would probably do that using a plugin.